# Error in IR receiver project

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, ir, code-optimization, ch340

I'm trying to receive remote information with an IR receiver and this is my code:

```
#include <IRremote.h>

int RECV_PIN = 11;
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
}

void loop() {
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
    Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
    irrecv.resume(); // Receive the next value
  }
  delay(100);
}
```

I tried to upload this to Arduino and it says:

```
exit status 1
redefinition of 'int RECV_PIN'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I can see no reason for it unless you didn't install the library properly, or the code you show isn't actually the code you are compiling.

Comment: I compiled your code. There is no compilation error. Probably, library problem. Install it properly.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the name `RECV_PIN` is used somewhere else, presumably in `IRRemote.h` -- although not in any version of it I can find.  Anyway, just change the name of `RECV_PIN` to something which doesn't conflict.

For example:

```
int MY_RECV_PIN = 11;
IRrecv irrecv(MY_RECV_PIN);
```